# validate required jquery doesnt work when i try to change rules

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 fields. I'm trying to insert a number into the first. The second value should be less or equal to the first field.

I'm using jquery validation to warn user, but when i do it it doesn't change the messages and layout.

I've tried to follow the documentation but doesn't understand what's wrong.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault-4">Quantidade permitida por pedido<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Produto.QuantidadeVenda, new { maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control", @id = "quantidade_pedido", placeholder = "0", validate = "required",@name = "quantidade_pedido" , @type = "number" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault-4">Possui regime de comodato<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.Produto.FlagComodato, new { @class = "chk-inativar switcher-example-default", @id = "comodato", @onclick = "checkComodato(this)" })
      </div>
</div>
<div id="limitEmprestimo" style="display: none" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="quantidade_comodato">Quantidade limite de empréstimo <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Produto.QuantidadeComodato, new { maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control", @id = "quantidade_comodato", placeholder = "0", validate = "required", @name = "quantidade_comodato", @type = "number"})
function checkComodato(check) {
    if (check.checked) {
        $("#limitEmprestimo").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#limitEmprestimo").hide();
    }
}

 $("#quantidade_comodato").focusout(function () {
    var quantc = $("#quantidade_comodato").val() === "" ? 0 : parseInt($("#quantidade_comodato").val());

    var quantp = $("#quantidade_pedido").val() === "" ? 0 : parseInt($("#quantidade_pedido").val());

    if (quantc > quantp) {

        var validator = $("#frmCadastro").validate();
        $("#quantidade_comodato").rules("remove", "required");
        $("#quantidade_comodato").rules("add", {
            max: quantp,
            messages: {
                quantp: "Invalid !"
            }
        });
        validator.element($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the jquery script is not within a `<script>` tag. Therefore the browser won't understand that your code should be run as javascript, instead the browser just thinks that your code is plain text.

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault-4">Quantidade permitida por pedido<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Produto.QuantidadeVenda, new { maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control", @id = "quantidade_pedido", placeholder = "0", validate = "required",@name = "quantidade_pedido" , @type = "number" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputDefault-4">Possui regime de comodato<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.Produto.FlagComodato, new { @class = "chk-inativar switcher-example-default", @id = "comodato", @onclick = "checkComodato(this)" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="limitEmprestimo" style="display: none" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="quantidade_comodato">Quantidade limite de empréstimo <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Produto.QuantidadeComodato, new { maxlength = "10", @class = "form-control", @id = "quantidade_comodato", placeholder = "0", validate = "required", @name = "quantidade_comodato", @type = "number"})
</div>

<script>

    function checkComodato(check) {
        if (check.checked) {
            $("#limitEmprestimo").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#limitEmprestimo").hide();
        }
    }

    $("#quantidade_comodato").focusout(function () {
        var quantc = $("#quantidade_comodato").val() === "" ? 0 : parseInt($("#quantidade_comodato").val());

        var quantp = $("#quantidade_pedido").val() === "" ? 0 : parseInt($("#quantidade_pedido").val());

        if (quantc > quantp) {

            var validator = $("#frmCadastro").validate();
            $("#quantidade_comodato").rules("remove", "required");
            $("#quantidade_comodato").rules("add", {
                max: quantp,
                messages: {
                    quantp: "Invalid !"
                }
            });
            validator.element($(this));
        }
    });

</script>
```

If that isn't the problem another typical one is that the jquery script is loaded in the end of the `_layout.cshtml`. So when you call jquery it haven't been defined yet. In that case you should get a script error in the developer console (hit F12 in your browser to show it).

That's easy corrected by wrapping the script in a Razor section.

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        // your code here
    </script>
}
```

"Scripts" is declared in `_Layout.cshtml` as `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to send the tag "</ script>" at the end, but it still doesnt work. When i take focus out to check the validation, the message and colors is wrong.

Comment: Add a screenshot to the question